# Is the matrix of the sum of two linear maps equal to the sum of the matrices of the two maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Is the matrix of the sum of two linear maps equal to the sum of the matrices of the two maps?

We have bases $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ of $W$.

$M(T+S) = M(T) + M(S)$?

Whenever $T,S\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$

---

What does this look like(in matrix form)? I can't imagine it for the general case, hence I am not sure how to verify it(For axler $2_{\mathbf{nd}}$ Edition, page $50$).

Is it something like:

$A\times M(T+S)=A\times M(T) + A\times M(S)$

---

I will fix the question after class, don't have time now(just the quality and my little effort shown)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Here is some lazy but hopefully clear notation.  If $x$ is a vector, then $[x]_B$ is the column vector relative to the basis $B$ (aka the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the basis).  Let $B_V$ and $B_W$ denote your choices of basis for the respective spaces.

From the definition of the matrix corresponding to a transformation, we have
$$
[Tx]_{B_W} = M(T) [x]_{B_V}
$$
Moreover, for any vectors $x,y$ in the same space, we have
$$
[x + y]_B = [x]_B + [y]_B
$$
It now follows that for any $x \in V$, we have
$$
M(S + T)[x]_{B_V} = \\
[(S + T)x]_{B_W} = \\
[Sx + Tx]_{B_W} = \\
[Sx]_{B_W} + [Tx]_{B_W} =\\
M(S)[x]_{B_V} + M(T)[x]_{B_V} = \\
(M(S) + M(T))[x]_{B_V}
$$
Since $M(S + T)[x]_{B_V} = (M(S) + M(T))[x]_{B_V}$ for any choice of $x$, we can conclude that $M(S+T)$ and $M(S) + M(T)$ must be the same matrices.

I think this is probably the clearest way to show this directly, but perhaps it is usually taken as a consequence of a broader statement.  At any rate, I hope this helps.