# A polynomial with a linear transformation as an argument

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\psi: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation and let $\psi^n$ be n- *th* power of $\psi$.
Let's consider a polynomial $P = a_nx^n + ...+a_0$ and let's define $P(\psi) = a_n\psi^n+...+a_1\psi+a_0$
The task is to decide whether $P(\psi)$ is a linear transformation.
What I know is that $\psi^n$ is a linear transformation however I don't know how to check if $P(\psi)$ is a linear transformation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove that

> If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations(with same domain and range), then $A+B$ is also a linear transformation.

Then prove that

> For a constant $c$, $cA$ is also a linear transformation.

Once you know these two, can you answer your question?

EDIT: In response to your comment you mentioned the $a_0$ annoying you. What you missed was that when you evaluate $P(A)$, the last term is not $a_0$ but $a_0\cdot I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. TO understand this see that $P(x)$ is a taking a point $x \in\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but $P(A)$ is taking a linear map to another linear map.

Comment: You might also be interested in reading about the characteristic polynomial :)

Comment: Also take a look here after you are done 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182994/is-the-matrix-of-the-sum-of-two-linear-maps-equal-to-the-sum-of-the-matrices-of

Comment: I managed to prove that both $A+B$ and $cA$ are linear transformations. Thus $P(\psi)$ is a linear transformation too? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, because you had already shown tha $A^n$ is a linear transform. So your $P(A)$ is just formed by multiplying linear transforms by constants and adding them. And by your proofs these combinations should also be linear transformations.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it :)  my biggest problems were linked to the constant $a_0$ I thought that $P(\psi)$ is a linear tranformation only when $a_0 = 0$

Comment: Actually you are missing something. I am mentioning it in my answer now.

Comment: Check the answer now

Answer (score 1):

The set of linear maps $V\to W$ is always a vector space (for the obvious notions of addition and scalar multiplication), so it is closed under forming linear combinations. If moreover $W=V$, then the space is closed under composition as well, so when it contains$~\psi$ it also contains all its powers$~\psi^k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ (to be honest, for $k=0$ this is not because of closure under composition, but because $\psi^0=I_V$ is linear). It follows that when the space contains$~\psi$, it contains all linear combinations of powers of$~\psi$, in other words all polynomials in$~\psi$.